# How to detect an error condition in functions called from the main function?

Tags: python

I have a small program which calls multiple functions from the `main()` function and in each of the functions there is a small probability, that an error occurs. In order to be compatible with the existing monitoring system, I need to make a file to `/var/tmp/error_triggered/` directory if there was at least one error or remove the file from this directory if there were no errors. One way to do this is to use variable with global scope:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import random
from pathlib import Path

def f1():
  global error
  for i in range(1, 5):
    if random.randint(0, 9) == 0:
      error = 1

def f2():
  global error
  for i in range(1, 5):
    if random.randint(0, 9) == 0:
      error = 1

def main():
  f1()
  f2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  error = 0
  main()
  if error == 1:
    Path('/var/tmp/error_triggered/' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]).touch()
  else:
    Path('/var/tmp/error_triggered/' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]).unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

It is usually a bad practice to modify a global variable from inside functions. Is it justified here? Or is there a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: It would be more usual to raise an exception in f1 and f2 if an error occurs. You can catch that in main and create the file.

Comment: Instead of using a global variable, you can have the functions return Falsy values in case of failures. You can collect the results in the `main` function and see if there are any Falsy values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of handling errors in Python is raising exceptions:

```
def f1():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        if random.randint(0, 9) == 0:
            raise ValueError()

def f2():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        if random.randint(0, 9) == 0:
            raise ValueError()

def main():
    f = Path('/var/tmp/error_triggered/' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0])
    try:
        f1()
        f2()
        f.unlink(missing_ok=True)
    except ValueError:
        f.touch()
```

There's a subtle difference between this and what you were doing: if `f1` raises an exception, `f2` won't be called (that is, raising an exception immediately stops the `try` block and goes straight to the `except`).  This is desirable behavior more often than not, since usually if an error happens you don't want to keep going with what you were doing.

If for some reason you want `f2` to be called even if `f1` has already produced an error, then it might be more appropriate to `return` the error the same way you'd return any other value:

```
def f1():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        if random.randint(0, 9) == 0:
            return 1
    return 0

def f2():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        if random.randint(0, 9) == 0:
            return 1
    return 0

def main():
    f = Path('/var/tmp/error_triggered/' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0])
    if f1() + f2():
        f.touch()
    else:
        f.unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

Using a `global` is almost **never** the best way to pass information between functions.  For anything beyond the simplest cases it will just make your code very difficult to debug.

Comment: I need to call `f2` even if there are errors in `f1`. In addition, the actual `f1()`, `f2()`, etc functions already return data like strings or lists. So I guess the best approach in that case would be to define a local `error = 0` in each function, set it to `1` if there is at least one error and finally return it like `return f_list, error` while calling the function with `f1_list, f1_error = f1()` from the `main()`? This would allow one to sum the `f1_error`, `f2_error`, etc codes and if the sum of those is not zero, then touch the file in the `/var/tmp/error_triggered/` directory.

Comment: Yup, returning multiple values as a tuple is the way to go, I think.  That's a pretty common pattern in languages that don't support exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating an `ERROR_COUNTER` int variable or dictionary which stores the counts, something like:

```
{ functionname: count, functionname2: count }
```

Which is updated with every occurence of an error.

Making variables `global` from inside functions is not great.

I don't know your use case/context specifically but you could also return an int of errors with each function call if all they do is perform an action. This would make the caller responsible for handling the count of errors than individual functions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd echo what some of the others have raised here, that raising exceptions is the appropriate response to errors but add that embedding a try/except loop if you need specific error behaviour:

```
def a():
    if random.randint(0, 9) == 0:
        raise Exception("error!")

def main():
    f = Path('/var/tmp/error_triggered/' + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0])
    try:
        for i in range(0,5):
            a()
        f.unlink(missing_ok=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        f.touch()
```

I'm assuming your code is a bit more complicated that raising errors at random, but the principles the same- if something hits and error, it should raise an exception, if you need to handle the exception in a way that isn't just leaving the shell, use a try/except loop.